# How to make compiler choose a non-member function overload

Tags: c++, c++17, overload-resolution

I am writing a library that performs some operations on built-in types (int, float, double, etc.) and user-provided types. One of those is performed by a template function:

```cpp
namespace lib
{
template<typename T>
inline auto from_string(std::string const & s, T & t) -> bool
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    iss >> t;
    return !iss.fail();
}
}
```

This is a customisation point - users may overload this functions for their type:

```cpp
namespace foo
{
class UserType
{
    // (...)
};
}

namespace lib
{
inline auto from_string(std::string const & s, foo::UserType & ut) -> bool
{
    // some implementation
}
}
```

or have the `from_string` function in the same namespace and accessible via ADL:

```cpp
namespace foo
{
inline auto from_string(std:string const & s, UserType & ut) -> bool
{
    // some implementation
}
}
}
```

Now, apart from string-to-type conversion, the library also performs type-to-string, comparison, and some more operations. I would like to have it done via a family of classes that hold the value as an instance of `std::any`:

```cpp
namespace lib
{
class TypeHandler
{
    public:
        virtual TypeHandler() = default;
        virtual auto from_string(std::string const & string, std::any & value) const -> bool = 0;
        // more functions
};

template<typename T>
class TypeHandlerT : public TypeHandler
{
    public:
        auto from_string(std::string const & string, std::any & value) const -> bool override
        {
            T val;
            if (from_string(string, val))  // an attempt to call the free function
            {
                value = val;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
}
}
```

I want to use the `TypeHandlerT` classes for convenience.

However, with the code like this I get the following compiler error when I try to use `TypeHandlerT<int>`:

```
error C2664: 'bool lib::TypeHandlerT<T>::from_string(const std::string &,std::any &) const':
cannot convert argument 2 from 'T' to 'std::any &' with [ T=int ]
```

It seems the member version of `from_string` hides the free function version.

Is there a way to fix this elegantly? For example by bringing the free function into scope (but how to do that without excluding ADL?)?

I know an easy fix is to rename either the member or free function, but I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scope based lookup starting from the body of `TestHandlerT<T>::from_string` hits the member function before it hits `lib::from_string`. So just reintroduce `lib::from_string` into the scope of the body with `using`. This also reenables ADL, as ADL is suppressed when scope based lookup hits a class member.

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeHandlerT : TypeHandler {
    bool from_string(std::string const &string, std::any &value) const -> override {
        using lib::from_string;
        T val;
        if (from_string(string, val)) {
            value = val;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but this will not work with the ADL-findable overload, would it?

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak No, it will do ADL, as I say. This is the *standard* way to do ADL-then-fallback lookups (e.g. it's [how the standard says](https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.requirements#swappable.requirements-example-1) you're supposed to use `std::swap`). Test it if you don't believe me.

Comment: It's not a matter of believing. I'm trying to understand :-) So, as you say scope based lookup starting from `lib::TestHandlerT<T>::from_string` hits the member function before it hits `lib::from_string`. It does not match, so the member overload should be rejected and lookup should continue. Is this correct? Also, by which mechanism does the ADL get reenabled if I bring the `lib::from_string` into scope by `using`? The case with `std::swap` is a bit different in my opinion.

Comment: Plain unqualified lookup generally only finds declarations from a single scope. If that's a member function or set of overloaded member functions, ADL does not apply. But with a `using` declaration in an inner scope, that declaration gets found instead of the member functions, and then ADL can apply and find additional declarations.

Comment: Name lookup and overload resolution are separate phases. Name lookup stops as soon as it finds an overload set in a given scope. Then overload resolution checks if any of those actually work. If none do, there is no backtracking (name lookup is not done again; hence your code fails). Name lookup has a special case for class members. If it hits a class member, ADL is skipped. If it doesn't, ADL is done and any declarations it finds are merged into the set from ordinary lookup. I already say how ADL is reenabled: the `using` declaration makes name lookup *not* hit a class member.

Comment: Thank you aschepler and HTNW. You made it clear for me.

Comment: Now I feel embarassed because I knew perfectly well that I could do `using lib::from_string`, but somehow I was not aware that this would enable ADL, and I did not check it myself. Well, life goes on :-)